# How to sync two threads in different classes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I need to have two threads synchronized such that both cannot run concurrently. Once called, they need to run so if the other thread is running, they need to wait until the other one is done and then run after it. I know I can use join() but my question involves threads in different classes with no reference to each other. Is it a good idea to make the threads static class variables so they both can access each other?

One thread (t1) is called from a method in the Main Activity and the other thread (t2) is inside an AsyncTask:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        public void someMethod()
        {
            // code
            Thread t1 = new Thread(() ->
        {
            // run thread code
        });
        t.start();
        try
            {
            t.join();
            }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // someMethod follow-up code
        }

    }

    public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        protected final Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // code
            Thread t2 = new Thread(() ->
        {
            // run thread code
        });
        t.start();
        try
            {
            t.join();
            }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // follow-up code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you feel the need to synchronize two threads, you probably need to re-think the logic of your app.

Comment: Lol no syncing threads is essential in multithreadimg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed the synchronization by adding static class thread variables and added a sleep factor so I could test:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Interface.InterfaceCommon
    {
    public static Thread t1;
    FetchData fetchData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        t1 = new Thread();
        fetchData = new FetchData();
        }
    public void someMethod()
        {
        Runnable r = () ->
            {
            try
                {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            /// Some code
            };
        t1 = new Thread(r);
        try
            {
            FetchData.t2.join();
            t1.start();
            }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class FetchData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
        {
        public static Thread t2;
        public FetchData()
            {
            t2 = new Thread();
            }
        protected final Void doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
            Runnable r = () ->
                {
                try
                    {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    /// Some code
                };
            t2 = new Thread(r);
            try
                {
                MainActivity.t1.join();
                t2.start();
                }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two blocking queues, one for each thread. They would each start working when they read from their queue, and they stop by writing to the other thread's queue. That way, there's always one that's active. They could pass just a token, or an object with data.